# in place replace with sed but only to keep a subset of the lines

Tags: sed

I want to run an inplace command for sed to keep only certain lines in a file. This is different from the usual usage where a sed `-i` with a substitution command is used to in-place substitute a files lines. For example, say I have this file:

```
> cat file.txt
fox
rabbit
fox
fox
wolf
```

and I want to only keep the lines matching fox. My idea was:

`sed -inr '/fox/p' file.txt`

but this does not work as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the fact that "-i" takes an optional argument so -inr is not the same as -i -n -r, it's the same as -i"nr". Try:

```
sed -i -nr '/fox/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
sed -i '/fox/!{s/.//g}' file
```

this will **empty** those unmatched lines by not delete them. So `fox` lines are staying in their places.

if you just want to delete those unmatched lines:

```
sed -i '/fox/!d' file
```